# Spivaks proof on the intermediate value theorem

Tags: calculus, limits, self-learning

I am a student trying to learn calculus and I've been working my way through spivaks calculus book and I am quite confused on his proof of the intermediate value theorem.

I understand how to use the intermediate value theorem but in his proof he states that if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $f(a)<c<f(b)$ then there is some $x$ in $[a,b]$ such that $f(x)=c$. His proof says that let $g=f-c$, then $g$ is continuous and $g(a)<0<g(b)$, then by theorem 1 (which is a theorem that I understand) there is an $x$ in $[a,b]$ such that $g(x)=0$, which means $f(x)=c$.

I looked online everywhere for a similar version of this proof to no avail. My question is how can we say that $g$ is continuous? It does not seem like a rigorous proof?

Comment: The difference of two continuous functions is continuous.

Comment: Please use MathJax to type your equations - it makes your question way more readable.
To answer your question: $g$ is the difference of the continuous function $f$ (which is continuous by assumption) and the continuous function $h=c$ (which is constant, and hence continuous).

Comment: To add a tiny bit more detail to the first comment above, we can think of that $c$ as just a constant function. Constant functions are continuous, and then the first theorem in the chapter on continuity says that sums (or differences) of continuous functions are continuous.

Comment: " then by theorem 1 (which is a theorem that I understand)"  Please state what the this theorem is.

Comment: $f(x)$ is continuous.  $c$ is a contstant.  So $g(x) = f(x) -c$ is continuous.  Does Spivak have a theorem (or property) that $f$ is continuous then $f(x) +c$ for any constant is continuous?

Comment: Although $c$ is a continuous function so sum/difference of two continuous functions is continuous applies, the proposition that a continuous function plus or minus a constant is more basic property and quiet easy to prove directly.

Comment: Hi! Try to prove it directly with the epsilon-delta definition of a continuous function. You can use the triangle inequality to exploit the continuity of the two individual functions.

Comment: "You can use the triangle inequality to exploit the continuity of the two individual functions." But it's even *easier* with a constant.  $f$ is continuous at $d$ means for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ so that $|x-d|<\epsilon$ will imply $|f(x)-f(d)| = |(f(x)-c) -(f(d)-c| =|g(x)-g(d)|< \epsilon$.  Therefore $g(x)=f(x)-c$ is continuous at $d$.

Comment: Note also, this is not a "proof of the intermediate value theorem" but rather a *variation* of the IVT. It is the IVT, stated differently. Spivak's proof of the IVT comes later, in chapter 8. Not trying to nitpick. Just offering this in case it might be relevant to your confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ is a continuous on $[a,b]$.  $c$ is a constant.

> Lemma: for any continuous function $f$  on $[a,b]$ and constant $c$, the function $g(x) =f(x) -c$ is continuous on $[a,b]$.

Pf:  Let $d \in [a,b]$.  $f$ is continuous at $x=d$ so $\lim_{x\to d} f(x) = f(d)$.  That means that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta>0$ so that $|x-d| < \delta$ will imply $|f(x) - f(d)| < \epsilon$.

But that means $|g(x) - g(d)| = |(f(x) -c) -(f(d) -c)| = |f(x) -f(d)| < \epsilon$.

That means using the same $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ that $\lim_{x\to d} g(x) = g(d)$.

Which means $g$ is continuous at $x = d$ for all $d \in [a,b]$.

Comment: This is very informative thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can think of $ c $ as a constant function, so it’s still a function and also a “very continuous” function. $ f $ is continuous by hypothesis. The linear combination, so sum, difference and multiplication by a number, of continuous functions is still a continuous function. If you want to understand why this is true, you can directly prove it using limits and their properties: remember that a function $ f $ is continuous at $x_0$ if and only if $ \lim _{ x \to x_0} = f(x_0) $.
It comes almost automatically by the properties of limits.